# Gnome seems to be overwriting my keymap configuration on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have finished several Arch Linux installations and I am in the process of creating my own custom installation script. It is almost finished but I have an issue with gnome overwriting (It's an assumption) the configuration applied by my script.

I have spent last 3 days trying everything on the wiki. From trying to set up it using xorg configuration files, /etc/xprofile, /etc/xinitrc and their home dir counterparts, localectl and setxkbmap.

The only thing that really works is setting the keymap through setxkbmap but it works when I do it in console (after gnome has loaded). I have tried to add the command to ~/.xinitrc and ~/.xprofile to make it persistent and it did not work either.

So, I'm a bit out of ideas and really tired of this because I want to start configuring other things and you know, spending 3 days only trying to configure the keyboard is not the best thing in the world.

I know I could use the Gnome configuratoin panel to easily change the layout but I want to do it from my installation script.

I have tried to use gsettings from install script to set the keymap, but it seems to onlywork when gnome is loaded up, so... no luck either.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help here.

P.D1: when gdm is loaded (the display manager) keyboard is ok smile.
P.D2: Localectl output:

```
System Locale: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
VC Keymap: es
X11 Layout: es
```

P.D3: $XDG_SESSION_TYPE is X11